# Cannot deploy the application with capistrano & passenger to Centos

Tags: apache, passenger, ruby-on-rails-5, centos7, capistrano3

I have Centos 7. I've installed Passenger & Apache. After deploying the application to the server with Capistrano. I get the error:

```
Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I've set owner group of working folder to apache (and nobody). But it is nothing.

My apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ...
   # Be sure to point to 'public'!
   DocumentRoot /home/kanna/www/bb/current/public
   <Directory /home/kanna/www/bb/current/public>
      # Relax Apache security settings
      AllowOverride all
      Require all granted
      # MultiViews must be turned off
      Options -MultiViews
      SetEnv GEM_HOME /home/kanna/www/bb/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I added line into Directory:

```
PassengerRuby /home/kanna/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/wrappers/ruby
```

If you want to see debug information you can add the line:

```
PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
```